# A transitive action of a non-cyclic group of order 8 on a set of 8 elements

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, group-actions

Can a non-cyclic group of order 8 act transitively on a set of 8 elements? From the orbit-stabilizer theorem I see that the transitive group action of a group of order 8 on a set of 8 elements is necessarily free but I do not see how to conclude that the group has to be cyclic.

Comment: Furthermore, a cyclic group does not need to act transitively. Take, for example the cyclic group generated by $(1,2)(3,4,5)$ (which has order 6).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, if the order of $G$ is $8$, the action of $G$ on $G$ defined by $L_g(x)=gx$ is transitive. Every group acts transitively on itself.